# Google Maps JS plugin not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps-api-3

I cannot get the google maps plugin to load correctly

How can I make it so that my contact form actually sends completed forms to my email or collects it in some way? I would eventually like to add a landing page that pops up thanking them for their form submission, (or maybe just add code to change the submit button to say "Thank you!" after clicked), but my first problem is the form has no way to save the info.

Thanks all!!

Comment: Hello Steve, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is rather broad, please provide code examples rather than just postin a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're missing a developer's API Key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

You can get a key here:
[Google API Key Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

FYI - You can see what issues your page has using the Developer Options menu in Chrome, or in Firefox by using the Web Developer Tool from the menu on the right.

As far as collecting information from a form, there are many samples online for saving form data, but they all depend on what development language you are using.